# Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number' when using property binding in an Angular template

Tags: angular, typescript

Getting the following errors:

```
Error: src/app/pages/journal-list/journal-list.component.html:27:23 - error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
    
    27 [title]="entry.title" [date]="entry.date"
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    
      src/app/pages/journal-list/journal-list.component.ts:7:16
        7   templateUrl: './journal-list.component.html',
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        Error occurs in the template of component JournalListComponent.
    src/app/pages/journal-list/journal-list.component.html:26:1 - error TS2322: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string | any[] | null | undefined'.
    
    26 [routerLink] ="i"
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    
      src/app/pages/journal-list/journal-list.component.ts:7:16
        7   templateUrl: './journal-list.component.html',
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        Error occurs in the template of component JournalListComponent.
```

Apparently because I'm using the property binding [date]="entry.date". I've declared property date as a number. Why does this occur?

Code snippet for context:

```
 <div class="entries-list">
<app-journal-entry *ngFor="let entry of entries; index as i"
[routerLink] ="i" 
[title]="entry.title" [date]="entry.date" 
[body]="entry.body"></app-journal-entry>

</div>
```

Comment: app-journal-entry component  date is number but you pass as string. so for that parseInt()  used

Comment: So what would that look like in my code example? [date]="parseInt(entry.date)"?

Comment: Here two option [date]="parseInt(entry.date)" or app-journal-entry component date make it "any" type. i would suggest first option.

Comment: The first option gives this error message: Property 'parseInt' does not exist on type 'JournalListComponent'. Changing the type to "any" just takes me back to square one, so it's complaining about string not being assignable to type number.

Comment: https://www.angularjswiki.com/angular/how-to-convert-a-string-to-number-in-angular-or-typescript/

Answer (score 15):

The error occurs when strictTemplates is enabled, i think its a bug.

You can use "$any(*)"

So instead of using
**[title]="entry.title"**

you should use
**[title]=$any(entry.title)**

For more information see the link
https://github.com/angular-split/angular-split/issues/220

Comment: Please consider giving some explanation to the OP why the problem is occurring and how your solution is solving the problem.

Comment: The error occurs when strictTemplates is enabled, i think its a bug.

Comment: Please edit the answer and add the explanation in the answer itself.

Comment: Looks like two bots talking to each other